# vmware_guest vs community.vmware.vmware_guest

Tags: ansible

Anyone knows the diff between

```
vmware_guest vs community.vmware.vmware_guest
```

Here are the urls

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/vmware_guest_module.html

Thanks

Comment: This is an overview of Ansible Collections. https://github.com/ansible-collections/overview/blob/main/README.rst It explains what they are, and why the product is moving to them over the monolithic ansible/ansible repository.  If you're running ansible 2.10 or later, you're running collections, if you're not using the Fully Qualified Collection Name, then ansible is making a best-guess as to which module you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Read the module documentation. Description and parameters will describe what they do.

Ansible 2.10 is the first release where most modules and plugins have moved to collections. Long fully-qualified names are the unambiguous way to refer to these.

Short names from 2.9 can still be used, due to compatibility redirects. As the [2.10 porting guide says first thing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.10.html), your playbooks should continue to work without any changes.

In theory, VMware collection maintainers could have removed the prefix on the name, resulting in `community.vmware.guest` but they didn't.